# Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: Error: LavaMoat - property "Proxy" of globalThis is inaccessible under scuttling mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, testing, next.js, metamask

I am developing a Next.js app and when I started making some tests with selenium-webdriver I started to get some problems. My webapp uses authentication with Metamask wallets. The problem is when trying to import a wallet on a test window with selenium to be able to log in after this in my webapp.
I have tried a lot of ways to do it:

- JavaScript tests trying to download metamask or trying to open a new chromewindow with metamask installed
- Python tests with auto-metamask, trying to import metamask in a new window...

I am on ubuntu 22.04. Chrome version is 113.0.5672.92, chromedriver version is 113.0.5672.63, selenium-webdriver version is 4.9.1, python3 version is 3.10.6.

### This is the code:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def test_login_button():
    EXTENSION_PATH = '/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn-10.30.1-www.Crx4Chrome.com.crx' # Path from the crx downloaded file in my pc (I have tried a bunch of them downloaded from different sites)
    SECRET_RECOVERY_PHRASE = "my seed phrase"
    NEW_PASSWORD = "password"

    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
    #opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions-except=nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn") (this approach does not work, I tried to disable all extensions except metamask but it does not work when executing the code because it does not find the extension)
    #opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir=./path/to/google-chrome/Profile 1") (this approach did not work when trying to open an existing profile)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    time.sleep(3)

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(3)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Importar una cartera existente"]'))) # This is the line which gives an error
    element.click()
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Importar una cartera existente"]').click()

    # Rest of the code
```

### ERROR obtained:

```
>       element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Importar una cartera existente"]')))

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7fcb4e1556f0>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exc...\\n#19 0x55775845dc97 \\u003Cunknown>\\n#20 0x55775846e113 \\u003Cunknown>\\n#21 0x7fdaf2c94b43 \\u003Cunknown>\\n"}}'}

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: Error: LavaMoat - property "Proxy" of globalThis is inaccessible under scuttling mode. To learn more visit https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat/pull/360.
E         at get (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/runtime-lavamoat.js:11200:17)
E         at serializationGuard (<anonymous>:198:67)
E         at buildError (<anonymous>:319:27)
E         (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.92)`
```

I have followed different tutorials:

- Main one is: https://dev.to/ltmenezes/automated-dapps-scrapping-with-selenium-and-metamask-2ae9
- auto-metamask library: https://pypi.org/project/auto-metamask/
- [Metamask automation with Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533462/metamask-automation-with-selenium-webdriver)

I just want to be able to make some tests to interact with a metamask wallet for my application to be able to log in it and then interact with the smart contracts that provide the logic.

Answer (score 5):

**IMPORTANT: This solution is working at 2023/05/15, it is important because two years ago this issue did not happen because this security implementation was not uploaded to the MetaMask extension. In a future this feature may change so this approach may not be usefull**

- One of the developers from MetaMask wrote me and shared a link to an issue where he specified the solution to the issue. See here: https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat/pull/360#issuecomment-1547726986
- *Summary of the thread's comment*: It seems LavaMoat is sandbox that is 'wrapping' the JavaScript code so that it has no access to some APIs that it should not and could cause a security issue. So when using an external webdriver, we will see this error because of that. His words are: 'This is a tradeoff we feel good about at the moment' because they prefer adding an extra security layer over letting the code accessing to APIs.

## Solution

- The developer told me was that I could build my own MetaMask version with this security feature disabled. This lowers the security but in my case there is no problem because I want to implement this just on development environment to test my Next.js app with selenium-webdriver.

#### Steps

1. Go to metamask-extension GitHub repo and clone it in your computer: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension. You can read the README.md file to find more information.
2. In the cloned folder, go to the `index.js` file, replace line 92 (`scuttleGlobalThis: applyLavaMoat && shouldScuttle`) with `scuttleGlobalThis: false`.
3. In the root folder of the project, run `cp .metamaskcr.dist .metamaskcr`.
4. Open the `.metamaskcr` file and change the following data:

   - `INFURA_PROJECT_ID='replace with your infura project id'`, see https://docs.infura.io/infura/, create an Infura account if you don't have one and create a project https://www.infura.io/.
   - `PASSWORD='replace with a password'` ;this is so you do not have to introduce it every time.
   - `SEGMENT_WRITE_KEY='replace with your segment write key'`, see https://segment.com/docs/connections/find-writekey/, create a Segment account if you do not have one and create a project https://segment.com/docs/connections/find-writekey/.
5. After this, run `yarn install` and `yarn dist` from the root folder of the project. This should generate a `/dist` folder with `/chrome` `/firefox` and `/sourcemaps` folders. The new EXTENSION_PATH from the python code should be the path to the `/chrome` folder in the project (or `/firefox` if you use firefox).

- So the final test code would be:

  ```
    def test_login_button():
        EXTENSION_PATH = '/home/adrib/Universidad/4o/TFG/Proyecto/metamask-extension/dist/chrome'

        opt = Options()
        opt.add_argument(f'--load-extension={EXTENSION_PATH}')

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opt)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        original_window = driver.current_window_handle

        time.sleep(3)

        time.sleep(3)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/input"))).click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/button"))).click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app-content']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button"))).click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app-content']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/footer/button[1]"))).click()
  ```

Special thanks to the developer from MetaMask who replied very quick and provided the thread from GitHub from which I got the answer to this problem, @weizman.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using python to click on the button, use python to send javascript command. Here a script that allow you to click on the button "Sign" :

````
```python
# JavaScript code to find the button with the text 'Next' and click it
javascript = """
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].textContent == 'Next') {
        buttons[i].click();
        break;
    }
}
"""

# Execute the JavaScript
driver.execute_script(javascript)

```
````